# layout_alignParentBottom does not work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I added an image in my android project. I tried to display it in the bottom of the scree with the following xml code in the image layout:

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
```

But the image keep displaying in the up.

What is the problem here ?

My android version is 4.1

here after the whole xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
/*
   Session screen layout

   Copyright 2013 Thincast Technologies GmbH, Author: Martin Fleisz

   This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0. 
   If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
*/
 -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/session_root_view"
    >

    <!-- childs are specified bottom-up so that we have a correct z-order in our final layout -->
    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/extended_keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.ScrollView2D
        android:id="@+id/sessionScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/extended_keyboard"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        >

        <com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.SessionView
            android:id="@+id/sessionView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
            />

    </com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.ScrollView2D>        

    <com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.TouchPointerView
        android:id="@+id/touchPointerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/touch_pointer_default"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.TxxTouchPointerView
        android:id="@+id/tmmTouchPointerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tmm_touch_pointer_default"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <android.widget.ZoomControls
        android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sessionScrollView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/extended_keyboard_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      
        />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: need more information.  can you post the rest of the xml?

Comment: @browep whole xml file added

Comment: i dont see any ImageView in the xml.  What are you adding the image to?

Comment: @browep It's the tag `com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.TxxTouchPointerView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is the image in question

```
<com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.TxxTouchPointerView
    android:id="@+id/tmmTouchPointerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"         
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tmm_touch_pointer_default"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

The `layout_height` is `match_parent`.  This means that it will be as vertically large as the parent so `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` means nothing.  Try with:

```
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 2):

put the image inside a Relative Layout

Answer (score 1):

You are setting its `layout_height="match_parent"` which means it always gets full height of its parent (your case is screen height), just set it to `layout_height="wrap_content"`. Same thing with `layout_width` if needed

See this

```
    <com.freerdp.freerdpcore.presentation.TxxTouchPointerView
    android:id="@+id/tmmTouchPointerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tmm_touch_pointer_default"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the RelativeLayout itself is not set *layout_height="match_parent"*.

update:

```
<RelativeLayout
    layout_height="match_parent"
    (...)
    >

    <ImageView
        layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        (...)
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: whole xml file added. The `layout_height="match_parent"` exists

Comment: Those browep and leegor already suggested are correct. The child ImageView itself should be *layout_height="wrap_content"* while the parent RelativeLayout is *layout_height="match_parent"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinearLayout instead, and set gravity to bottom as follows:

android:gravity="bottom"